# saving unknown amount of int and char input

Tags: c++, char, save, int

Hi I am trying to save an unknown number of inputs of char and int then padding them to a function called push but i realize that the method I am using will change the input of the int save from e.g. 13 to 1 and 3. thus , i would like to ask if there is any other method for this? thanks and sorry for the noob qn asked as I just started on c++.

```
    char input;
    int inNum;
    Stack st;

    cout << "Enter an expression: " << endl; 

    while(cin >> input)
    {
        if (input != '+' && input != '-' 
            && input != '/' && input != '*' 
            && input != '=')
        {
            inNum = input - '0';
            cout << inNum << endl;
            st.push(inNum);
        }
    }
```

Comment: for starters if input is supposed to read characters it should be a `char`

Comment: I am sorry i make a typo error

Comment: Do the expressions have a specific form? or is this supposed to be a general expression parser?

Comment: the expression is something like 1 + 2 + 3 / 4 + 5 * 6 that kind

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can utilize `isdigit` from `<cctype>` and the `istream` functionality of `putback` to accomplish your parsing technique.

```
char c;
int i;

while(cin >> c) {
  if(isdigit(c)) {
    cin.putback(c);
    cin >> i; //read my integer
  }
  else {
    //handle operator
  }
}
```

You can also utilize the `peek` function to look at the next character before reading. If it is a digit then parse like normal. Ignore white-space manually when you use this.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the inputs it's hard to say, but if your input only consists of numbers and operations (+,-,*,/,=), then with the least amount of modification you can do something like:

```
string numBuffer;
while(cin >> input)
{
    if (input != '+' && input != '-' 
        && input != '/' && input != '*' 
        && input != '=')
    {
        temp += input;
    } else {
        st.push(atoi(numBuffer.c_str()));
        numBuffer = "";
    }
}
```

while you're reading in the characters, as long as you haven't read an operation yet, you're building up a number string, and only when you've read an operation do you know you have a complete number.

Answer (score 0):

If you read a number, just concatenate it to the previous one -if there was one before-, other wise store it. That way, if you have `13+1`, it will find `1` first, then `3` but the previous thing found was a number also so it becomes `13`. Then you find `+`, so you store `13` somewhere (in a vector or else). Etc